# Meaning of advertising logos

Tags: logo, advertising

I've seen many advertising logos, they are quite simple and don't show anything related to advertising. I saw some with call out signs but this is not the only thing,i think. I'm curious to know about what should be there in an advertising company logo.

Thanks

Comment: This is a discussion, which is not on-topic for us. What is an "advertising logo" as opposed to some other kind of logo? How are they "not related to advertising"? What was the context? What is the "meaning" you're asking about? This is too broad for us to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Logo & branding are the key pillars of a company's identity. The logo should be able to be recognized by people.
It does not matter whether the logo is simple or not. The important thing is it should be solid enough for recognition.
A few things could be considered for an advertising logo:

- **Initials** (You could use the company initials as the logo)
- **Types of services** (If you provide billboard advertising, a flat billboard could be included in the logo)
- **Play of words** (Adding creativity to your logo)
- **Colors** (Choosing one or two main colors)

For more inspiration and ideas, you could look around on [Dribbble](http://dribbble.com)